# Single page query with django-rest-framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a question about **django-rest-framework**. How to list all objects in a query in a single page or without pagination?

It is possible to use *PageNumberPagination* pagination_class and setting *page_size* enormously large integer. However, It seems ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a generic view, you should be able to set `PAGE_SIZE = NONE` to disable pagination entirely: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#page_size

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `PAGE_SIZE=NONE` to your settings.py

Comment: Thank you. In a view, inhereted from `ListAPIView`, `PAGE_SIZE = None` also works.